# Oracle Keep Alive Test SQL_NET.EXPIRE_TIME not working

Tags: oracle, firewall, database-administration

I have been trying to successfully configure oracle database 11g with dead connection detection keep alive settings without changing any tcp settings. I went into `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/sqlnet.ora` and set the oracle keep alive to 10 minutes `(SQL_NET.EXPIRE_TIME = 10)`. I also went into tnsnames.ora file and added the `ENABLE=BROKEN` parameter to the net_service_name. In one terminal I find the Oracle session process ID and then open a second terminal where I use the Linux trace tool to verify there is a write after 10 minutes. Unfortunately there is no write after 10 minutes. The only time there is a write is when the original oracle session being traced is disconnected or there is activity being performed in this session. I am trying to figure out how to resolve the issue of not seeing a write every 10 minutes to verify the server process sent an empty packet to the client.

Comment: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/oraclenetdcd-2179641.pdf

Comment: https://prashantatridba.wordpress.com/tag/sqlnet-expire_time/